How to get cross domain authentication data from different web apps
I have two separate web applications say App1 and App2 which has different authentication mechanisms. I have another web application App3 where I can login with either App1 or App2. If a user is already logged in and a session is active in either App1/App2 in a browser tab, I wanted to access the App3 directly through a URL in the same browser via a new tab. I am planning to use a token exchange grant type approach in OAuth 2.0 to achieve this where the JWT token from App1 or App2 is validated and exchanged in App3 authentication service so that App3 resources can be accessed with the exchanged token. Right now, the JWT token to be exchanged is residing in the browser local storage of App1/App2 which are in separate domains. In a scenario where a direct URL of App3 is entered in the address bar of a new tab of the same browser, I need to retrieve the JWT token of App1 or App2 to exchange it with App3 auth service. Is there a better approach to get the token in App3 from another web app(App1/App2) which is in another domain through a secure way? I am using Angular frontend and .NET Core backend with IdentityServer4.

I suggest you could consider using identity server's SSO , you could configure it to recognize the three app.

Seems like you want SSO here, but the only way I know of to transmit data across domains/processes is using the messaging API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage  (this might open up some security holes, though)  Probably an easier way to deal with this is keep all apps same-domain.  (they could be served from different folders and keep same domain...)

The problem is I don't have a common Identityserver here for these 3 apps. Hence I am trying to exchange the existing access token using exchange token grant type in OAuth in the authorization service of my app where it will be validated and a new token is generated. But I couldn't find a secure way to get the token from other app domain to exchange it with my application auth service/Identityserver. I tried cookies which is actually working but I am not sure if its a standard way and it might open up security holes.
